# COMPOUND BORDER : Get a outline border with title outside the Jpanel in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, border

My only problem is that I don't know how to put my border outside the panel. I've tried compound and some other border code but so far I am unable to put it outside. It either disappears or it doesn't change at all.

The output that I want:

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

The output that I'm getting :

[image: CURRENT OUTPUT]

I'm a newbie at swing and I have been searching and found out about compound border but I am still not so familiar on how it works with adding the buttons into the panel. (I've removed the code of me trying to do compound border because it was just a mess full of errors)

THE CODE :

```java
package activityswing;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


public class swing {
public static void main (String args []) {
     JFrame pa= new JFrame("Swing Activity");
        //boarder
        pa.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            //buttons
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
        JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");

        //label
        JLabel lb1= new JLabel("Panel 1");
        JLabel lb2= new JLabel("Panel 2");

        //adding label to panel
        lb1.add(panel1);
        lb1.add(panel2);

        //panel1
        Border line1 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
        panel1.setBorder(line1);
        panel1.add(button1);
        panel1.add(button2);
        panel1.add(button3);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 1"));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,40));

        //panel2
        Font font2 = new Font("Verdana",Font.ITALIC,12);
        Border line2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue);
        lb2.setFont(font2);
        panel2.setBorder(line2);
        LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();  
        panel2.setLayout(layout);
        panel2.add(button4);
        panel2.add(button5);
        panel2.add(button6);
        panel2.add(lb2);
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel 2"));
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,40));

        //FRAME
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50,50);
        pa.setLayout(flow);
        pa.pack();
        pa.add(panel1);
        pa.add(panel2);
        pa.setSize(700,200);
        pa.setResizable(false);
        pa.setVisible(true);
        pa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pa.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
}
```

Comment: Don't add components to labels.  Don't mess with the preferred size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add component to labels

```
lb1.add(panel1);
lb1.add(panel2);
```

Labels calculate their preferred size based the label properties (text/icon/font/etc) and not the child components.

Don't mess with the `preferredSize` of the components unless you are absolutely certain you willing to take over all the responsibility to calculate the components size.

The simple solution would be to create a instance of `TitledBorder` yourself, for example...

```
Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 12);
TitledBorder border = new TitledBorder("Panel 1");
border.setTitleFont(font2);
```

I'd kind of tempted to create a factory method to make this easier, but you get the general idea

To get the border "separated" from the component, I would use a compound component approach, where the outer panel contains the title and then add the inner panel into it.

If needed, you could use `CompoundBorder` and use a `EmptyBorder` on the side of the outer panel

Have a look at:

- [JavaDocs for `TitledBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html)
- [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

... for more details

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame pa = new JFrame("Swing Activity");
        //boarder
        pa.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panels
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        //buttons
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
        JButton button6 = new JButton("Button 6");

        Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 12);
        TitledBorder border1 = new TitledBorder("Panel 1");
        border1.setTitleFont(font2);
        
        JPanel outter1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        outter1.setBorder(border1);
        panel1.add(button1);
        panel1.add(button2);
        panel1.add(button3);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        outter1.add(panel1);

        //panel2
        LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();
        TitledBorder border2 = new TitledBorder("Panel 2");
        JPanel outter2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        outter2.setBorder(border2);
        
        panel2.setLayout(layout);
        panel2.add(button4);
        panel2.add(button5);
        panel2.add(button6);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        outter2.add(panel2);

        //FRAME
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 50);
        pa.setLayout(flow);
        pa.add(outter1);
        pa.add(outter2);
        pa.pack();
        pa.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pa.setVisible(true);
        pa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pa.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest `JPanel`s. That is how I implemented the *output you want*.

The below code is not a correction of your code, it is an example of how to achieve the output you want. Since the two `JPanel`s in your code are quite similar, the below code only displays a single `JPanel`. I assume you can make the appropriate changes.

```java
package activityswing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Swing2 {
    private JPanel createInner() {
        JPanel inner = new JPanel();
        inner.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        inner.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        inner.add(button2);
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        inner.add(button3);
        return inner;
    }

    private JPanel createOuter() {
        JPanel outer = new JPanel();
        TitledBorder titledBorder = new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue), "Panel 1");
        Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12);
        titledBorder.setTitleFont(font2);
        EmptyBorder emptyBorder = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        CompoundBorder compoundBorder = new CompoundBorder(titledBorder, emptyBorder);
        outer.setBorder(compoundBorder);
        outer.add(createInner());
        return outer;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createOuter());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Swing2().showGui());
    }
}
```

Running the above code displays the following window.

[image: screen capture]